# Firebase Browser Notification: Not able to send Customized Message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, firebase, push-notification, customization, firebase-cloud-messaging

We have developed a Web Application in ASP.NET MVC and implemented Browser Notification via Firebase.

The notification is working fine but every time a Notification is triggerred it is always showing the same message as mentioned below:

"Hey, There is an update. Please visit our website".

We are not able to dynamically customized the message in the Notifications.

Had contacted Google Support, But they told us to get help from Stack Overflow.

It will be great if you guys can help us out with the issue as we stuck and not able to move ahead.

Please find below the code as requested:

```
sw.js:

use strict;

console.log('Started', self);

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
self.skipWaiting();  
console.log('Installed', event);
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
console.log('Activated', event);
});

 self.addEventListener('push', function (event) {
event.waitUntil(
     self.registration.pushManager.getSubscription().then(function    (subscription) {
      var notificationsPath = 'http://localhost:11546?endpoint=' + encodeURIComponent(subscription.endpoint);
      var headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
      return fetch(notificationsPath, { headers: headers }).then(function (response) {
          return response.json().then(function (notifications) {
              return Promise.all(
                notifications.map(function (notification) {
                    return self.registration.showNotification(notification.title, {
                        body: notification.body,
                        //icon: notification.icon_url
                    });
                })
              );
          });
      }).catch(function (xhr, status, error) {
          console.error('Unable to retrieve the server.', error);
      });
  })
);
});
```

windows service:

```
WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
            tRequest.Method = "post";
tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
var objNotification = new
            {
                to = "fQLxHW2fzuc:APA91bEkGKWqVlmZkM_Z9rZTF5bYbytOOsHFbfg7lL1vVzb6XycWkf-0NuMSdwo7hfpSlNuVBbx7o4i-E549eVCkvBbtPEb-dohuHiKLg18ROthj6ds3QIYyZKi_dsrHBn-uNxKGOhX-",                   
                data = new
               {
                    body = "This is the message",
                   title = "This is the title"
               }

            };
string jsonNotificationFormat = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
            Byte[] byteArray =       Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonNotificationFormat);
tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", "AAAA80JHkUE:APA91bG2LuMawMpo9TiWbDxbc3GBRVbERu3TyKZIbNb_jTMs5C4q_pQrjLmF5-QJFGgj3FzMthR16nFCi2qrYOlCDrPvFop1uhlqMIMEoKaJsUu7vUZjKMvwazWZFbgalKEb1uhbOCIK7YK5yotusvbwyPO60pgANw"));
 tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", "1044789039425"));
            tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            tRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
            using (Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

                using (WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream dataStreamResponse = tResponse.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResponse))
                        {
                            String responseFromFirebaseServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();

                            FCMResponse response = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FCMResponse>(responseFromFirebaseServer);
                            if (response.success == 1)
                            {
                                //new NotificationBLL().InsertNotificationLog(dayNumber, notification, true);
                            }
                            else if (response.failure == 1)
                            {
                                //new NotificationBLL().InsertNotificationLog(dayNumber, notification, false);
                                //sbLogger.AppendLine(string.Format("Error sent from FCM server, after sending request : {0} , for following device info: {1}", responseFromFirebaseServer, jsonNotificationFormat));

                            }

                        }
                    }

                }
            }


manifest.json:

{
  "name": "MVCNotificationsAPI",
  "gcm_sender_id": "1044789039425"
}


main.js

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
console.log('Service Worker is supported');
navigator.serviceWorker.register('../sw.js').then(function () {
    return navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
}).then(function (reg) {
    console.log('Service Worker is ready :^)', reg);

    reg.pushManager.subscribe({ userVisibleOnly: true }).then(function (sub) {
        console.log('endpoint:', sub.endpoint);
        document.getElementById("Hidden1").value = sub.endpoint;
    });
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log('Service Worker error :^(', error);
});
```

}

We are facing an issue where we are not able to dynamically change the Data for the below mentioned code section:

```
  data = new
               {
                    body = "This is the message",
                   title = "This is the title"
               }
```

As whenever we are setting the Data Dynamically, the Notifications are not being triggered and also we are not getting any error on our IDE or on the Firebase account.

Comment: Please post the [minimal code needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hello, I have edited my question and posted the Source code for reproducing the problem. Please let me know in case of any concerns.

Comment: hello, we have managed to solve the dynamic problem but now we are facing an issue where an icon is not being displayed on mobile browser notification. Can you please help?

Comment: @VineetMore how dod you solve it ? I'm trying to implement the same concept but I'm not receiving the notification on my browser